# Let user know their email to document library was rejected

Tags: 2010, email, email-enabled-library

I have several email enabled document libraries, all set to "Accept e-mail messages based on document library permissions".

It works fine, but sometimes users will choose the wrong list or send it from the wrong email address.  Is there any way to make sharepoint send a message back that their email was rejected?

Right now it silently fails and users are left wondering where the heck their files went.

If there is no built in setting, are there any third party solutions that achive this?  Googling has turned up nothing, but perhaps I'm using the wrong search terms.